# Disable speakers on Windows client machines?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-7, group-policy, windows-xp

I am looking for a way with which I can completely disable Windows-audio-output on on a group of computers that our students use.

Ideally, I would like to disable it only for students and enable it for teachers (who are in different groups).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the Windows Audio service via GP, located at:

> Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\System Services\Windows Audio

(Admins would be able to enable it manually, but hopefully your students aren't admins.)

Or if it has to be user-based, you could try creating an ADM Template to do it, [like in this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/winserverGP/thread/4d40d1aa-8ced-4322-8171-6384ae682feb) (though I've never personally tried this, and it does require finding the audio driver reg key, so hopefully you don't have different sound cards in your environment).

Comment: Hopefully the teachers aren't admins, either.